# We shouldn't allow questions about current developing series?

Tags: discussion

I found this specific question about the serie Mr. Robot [and what happened](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41238/what-happened-to-tyrell-wellick) with one of the main characters. Mr. Robot (putting some context) is right now developing the story and ask things while it's not over the season (not the whole serie), I think is unnecesary. We can easily wait the next chapter or the entire season to finish and if you have any question, there you can ask about a specific scene or character.

Is it correct anyway to ask questions about it? The season is not over yet, my suggestion is wait for it and then start asking question.

Comment: So basically you think we should wait a year to ask any question?

Comment: A season doesn't extend for a year. That's why I clarified the season, not the entire season.

Comment: Some do. Gravity falls was a year and a half. Most are at least 6 months if no breaks. 24 weeks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be overly restrictive to say you can't ask *any* questions about an ongoing series. Plenty of questions can be easily answered just based on what has already aired.

Asking questions about things that have not *yet* happened tend to fall under the existing close reason of "primarily opinion-based", because all of the answers are just one person's opinion on what is likely to happen. If there is concrete evidence about what's going to happen in the future, from a reliable source (e.g. the producers), those questions become answerable, and are fine.

So, in general, I don't think we need any special rule about ongoing series. Deal with the questions on a case-by-case basis: if they are answerable, they're on-topic, if they aren't, they are off-topic for other reasons.